# An internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have webapp in spring 3 , spring data (with jpa). When I try to load from db details of product the server gives the message: HTTP Status 500 -The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. I can write datas in db (no problem) and display all products but can't show details. I don,t know what is going on (I try on tomcat 7.042 and VMware v 2.9 the same results on both). Here are my codes:
entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
public Long id;

private String author;

@Lob
private byte[] cover;

private String description;

private float price;

private String title;

private String year;

public Product() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return this.author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public byte[] getCover() {
    return this.cover;
}

public void setCover(byte[] cover) {
    this.cover = cover;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getYear() {
    return this.year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}
```

}

repository interface:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,      Long>,PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p")
public Page<Product> takeAll( Pageable pageable);
@Query("select p from Product p where p.id = ?1")
public Product takeByTitle( Long id);

   }
```

dao:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductDAO {
@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

public Page<Product> showAllProducts(Pageable pageable){
return productRepository.takeAll(pageable);
}

public Product searchByDetails(Long id){
 return productRepository.takeByTitle(id);
}
}
```

endpoint:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ProductEndpoint {

@Autowired
ProductDAO productDAO;
public Page<Product> getAll(Pageable pageable){
return productDAO.showAllProducts(pageable);
}
public Product TakeDetails(Long id){
 return productDAO.searchByDetails(id);
}
}
```

controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
ProductEndpoint productEndpoint;
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showHome(Model model, Pageable pageable){
Page<Product> product = productEndpoint.getAll(pageable);
model.addAttribute("product", product.getContent());
model.addAttribute("page", product.getTotalPages());
model.addAttribute("pageNumber", product.getNumber());
return "index";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showById(@RequestParam(value = "id")Long id, Model model){
model.addAttribute("product", productEndpoint.TakeDetails(id));
return "details";
 }
 }

  @Controller
  public class DetailsController {
@Autowired
ProductEndpoint productEndpoint;
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showDetails(@PathVariable("id") Model model){
    model.addAttribute("product");
    return "details";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/details/addtocart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addToCart(){
return "redirect:/cart";
}
}
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="HTML 5 CSS 3 Spring Form"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<script src="../../js/libs/ajax.js" th:src="@{/js/libs/ajax.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" align="center">
  <form method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>#</td>
<td></td>
<td align="center"><b>TITLE</b></td>
<td ><b>PRICE</b></td>
<td ></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr th:each="sb, poz : ${product}">
<td th:text="${poz.count}">1</td>
<td ><img th:src="${sb.cover}" alt="cover"/> </td>
<td th:text="${sb.title}"></td>
<td th:text="${sb.price}"></td>
<td><a th:href="@{/details(id=${sb.id})}" >DETAILS</a></td>
<td ><b><a th:href="@{/cart(orderId=${sb.title})}" >ADD TO CART</a></b></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
     </form>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
</body>
   </html>
```

and details.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="HTML 5 CSS 3 Spring Form"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    </head>
<body >
<div id="container" align="center">
    <header> </header>
 <form method="get" th:object="${product}">
    <table border="1">
    <tr th:each="sb : ${product}">
    <td><b>TITLE :</b></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.title}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>AUTHORS :</b></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.author}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>DESCRIPTION :</b></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.description}">D
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>PRICE :</b></td>
    <td th:text="${sb.price}">$ 39</td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
   </form>
  <p>
   <a th:href="@{/}">Return to home</a>
</p>    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
<!--! end of #container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thank for help.

Comment: Could you post the error stack? And is it a typo in "@Query("select p from Product p where p.id = ?1")
public Product takeByTitle( Long id);"? There is an extra "1" behind "?".

Comment: Make sure you registered the `PageableArgumentResolver` as documented in http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#web-pagination. Otherwise Spring MVC will not be able to call your controller method taking a `Pageable`. If you're on Spring Data JPA 1.4 M1 you can simply use `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` in your configuration.